# How to use props variable for css-modules className?

Tags: reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

Is it possible to use a props variable for a css-modules className?

```
// Component.js
import styles from "./Component.module.scss"

const Component = ({ color }) => 
    <div className={`${styles.component}` `${styles.color}`>
        Component
    </div>

// Component.module.scss
.component { border: 1px black solid; }
.red { color: red; }
.green { color: green; }
```

Then I could use the `Component` like so:

```
// App.js
<Component color="red" />
<Component color="green" />
```

And have the two `Components` be red and green respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've missed a bracket

```
const Component = ({ color }) => {
    const cssColor = color;
    return (
        <div className={`${styles.component}` `${styles[cssColor]}`}>
            Component
        </div>
    )
}
```

To use `Component` level CSS you can get it loaded in your webpack as using a loader ([Reference](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/05/styling-components-react/#css-modules))

When using webpack, you can add the loader and also include the module to your webpack.config.js in other to make CSS modules work with Webpack.

```js
test: /\.css$/,
loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' 
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a library called [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames)

Answer (score 0):

```
import styles from "./component.module.css";

const Component = ({ color }) => {
    const cssColor = styles[color];
    return (
        <div className={cssColor}>
            Component
        </div>
    )
}
```

I think this operation works better

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Following works:

```
const Component = ({ color }) => {
    const cssColor = color;
    return (
        <div className={`${styles.component}` `${styles[cssColor]}`>
            Component
        </div>
    )
}
```